# Insert HTML Fragment containing Directive into DOM via jQuery and trigger Directive code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are doing an in-place migration to Angular (1.x). Mostly primary components, like the grid and associated functionality. Trying to reuse existing (jQuery centric) code where possible.

I click on the Details link in a table row, and I request the details page from the server, which is returned as an HTML fragment (containing HTML, and template in script blocks). While still in my Angular controller, I take the HTML fragment and insert it using jQuery:

```
$('#DetailsContent').html(htmlData);
```

That all works great, except that I want to start putting some directives (reuse, etc) in that HTML fragment that is generated on the server. Using the above, the directive is output into that `div#DetailsContent`, but the directive code isn't called. I tried to compile the HTML fragment:

```
$('#DetailsContent').html($compile(htmlData)($scope));
```

But what I got was an error: *Syntax error, unrecognized expression:*

I reduced the HTML generated on the server to just the directive I'm using, which works fine in other pages and still get the same error. Finally, I reduced it even further to the following and get the same error. I've verified in DevTools and the debugger that the response is nothing other than the below string.

```
<div>this is a test</div>
```

Any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

***Update:***

Using the pointer from @harunurrashid, I was able to resolve the issue. Here is my codepen with the solution:
https://codepen.io/edsinek/pen/grJNWy

Comment: I think this discussion would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570441/angular-directives-in-http-response

Comment: Append your html to document flow first, and then re-fetch the element by query selector to do compile work.